# How to use volume keys for scrolling? (everywhere)

Tags: buttons

I would like to use volume keys for scrolling (lists, homescreens, icons, documents -  anything which now does require you to swipe finger in order to scroll - just like my old java phone where you could scroll using screen gestures AND volume rocker as well); 
would it be possible?

I have Samsung SGH T679 (android 2.3.5)

I have tried ButtonRemapper but it didn't help (it did not show volume keys as customizable buttons)

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: yes, I am rooted

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, there is no way to do this system-wide without heavily modifying the ROM, or at least system files. Especially if ButtonRemapper doesnt show your volume keys as programmable buttons, then it won't be easy. Some apps will, however, let  you customise their behaviour. For example, I know browsers such as Dolphin and Miren as well as Google Reader can change the volume button's behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

[This XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=7834210&postcount=1) describes how to change the key remapping. However, as the file(s) are in the /system folder, I believe one needs the device to be rooted.

> you need to edit the files english.us.kl and qwerty.kl found in `/system/usr/keylayout` folder.
>
> Open each of the 2 files and replace:
>   "key 115 VOLUME_UP" with "key 115 DPAD_UP"
>   "key 114 VOLUME_DOWN" with "key 114 DPAD_DOWN"
>
> Save the files and restart

On my Galaxy S2, I only found the qwerty.kl file. Haven't touched it as I'm not brave enough. :-)

Do report back if this works and of course, make a complete backup of your device before you attempt this.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it (once I'll get a reliable way to restore the phone in case it's bricked - or I'll get convinced this action will not brick my phone). Thanks again!

Comment: Perform a nandroid backup - that should get you a safety net.

Answer (score 0):

You'd most definatly require root access for that. Then flash a ROM which supports volume key scrolling.

Comment: I've never seen a ROM with volume key scrolling.